# Find row name based on cell value & column name in R

Tags: r, dataframe

Say I have this data frame `df` :

```
   |c1 |c2 |c3 |c4 |
r1 | 2 | 3 | 3 | 5 |
r2 | 5 | 8 | 6 | 1 |
```

Note that all the column values are unique, but some cell values repeat (`3` and `5`). I'd like to find out the name of the row containing `5` in column `c4` (in this case, it would return `"r1"`).

I've found SO questions about finding the row name based on just cell value, which doesn't work when different cells can have the same values. I've also found questions about finding the row *index* based on the cell value and column *index*, but I need to be able to do this in a scenario where I might know the indices that correspond to the column/row names. But based on the answers I found for those questions, I've tried the following 4 methods, and none have worked:

```
# 1
df[max(df$c4), "c4"]

# 2
which(df == max(df$c4), arr.ind=TRUE)

# 3
rownames(df)[max(df$c4), "c4"]

# 4
row(df$c4, max(df$c4))
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want row name based on max value in `c4` use :

```
rownames(df)[which.max(df$c4)]
#[1] "r1"
```

Or if there could be multiple max value use :

```
rownames(df)[df$c4 == max(df$c4)]
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(c1 = c(2L, 5L), c2 = c(3L, 8L), c3 = c(3L, 6L), 
c4 = c(5L, 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("r1", "r2"))
```